# What's the link between universal approximation theorem and orthogonal basis functions?

Tags: functional-analysis, fourier-analysis, machine-learning, orthogonal-polynomials

I'm a novice when it comes to the world of machine learning, but when attempting to understand the universal approximation theorem I've acquired the notion that a neural network can represent any function by approximating it with a weighted sum of sigmoids (I got this notion from [this](https://hackernoon.com/illustrative-proof-of-universal-approximation-theorem-5845c02822f6) article). This sounds a lot to me like the expression of any function using orthogonal basis functions, like Legendre polynomials, Hermite polynomials, Chebyshev polynomials, and Fouirer series/transforms, able to approximate any function with a weighted series of orthogonal functions. Where's the link here? I don't suppose sigmoids are orthogonal functions, but they seem to be able to accomplish the same thing.

Come to think of it, why don't we use orthogonal functions to handle this goal of approximating any continuous, compact function that seems to be so crucial in ML?

Comment: You can. Nobody is saying you can't either. In fact, polynomials are often used for regression problems in ML and Fourier transforms are fundamental for time series analysis.

Comment: @TheDude How come sigmoids are favored then?

Comment: Sigmoid activation functions were used in the proof of the universal approximation theorem for ANNs, hence they give a guarantee, which makes them a popular choice. 

How to approximate a function has been a question since at least Gauss, if not earlier, and they obviously didn't have ANNs, so they used what they had. There exist similar approximation guarantees for these techniques. 

ANNs are just the fad nowadays because they work well on the types  of problems the world is interested in at the moment.